# Why isn't 'nethogs' installed with the setuid bit set?

Tags: security, setuid

I've been using `nethogs` for a while now, having to `sudo` every time, while `ping` has the setuid bit set. Today I set it for nethogs and it works:

```
$ ls -l $(which nethogs) $(which ping)
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  64496 Nov  2  2011 /usr/sbin/nethogs
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 44168 May  7 17:21 /bin/ping

$ sudo chmod u+s  $(which nethogs)

$ ls -l $(which nethogs)
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 64496 Nov  2  2011 /usr/sbin/nethogs

$ nethogs
```

Can you think of any reason not to install it by default like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ping` is setuid because it, while fairly "safe", requires the ability to open raw sockets. Consequently [it needs the `CAP_NET_RAW`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ping) capability, or to be root.

`nethogs` is different for a few reasons: notably, it not only requires privileged access to the networking stack, but it shows information about other users. On a multi-user system you may not want just any user to be able to see who's using what.

Another reason is that `nethogs` is a fairly complicated program. Programs that run setuid [need to be extra-secure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid#Security): a buffer overflow, say, could lead to arbitrary privilege elevation. `ping` takes quite some care to be secure, and even detects who's actually running it to behave differently (`ping -f` only works if you're actually root, for example). It's easier to be confident about that in a small non-interactive program than in a larger tool like `nethogs`.

Requiring the user to have root access already avoids those sorts of concerns, or delegates them to `sudo`. There's no(t as much) concern about privilege elevation when you're already root. In general, programs aren't made setuid-by-default unless it's vitally necessary to their function, like `passwd`.

That said, on a single-user system, or one where you're not concerned about those issues, making it setuid for your own convenience isn't a significant problem.

Comment: That's close to what I suspected (complexity and being able to snoop on other users' activity). It's good to have some educated confirmation. Thanks!